# @Valid in dropwizard API resource

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am trying to use @Valid in dropwizard before the object is consumed by the API. However, none of the attributes of the object are getting validated as it seems validation is not happening? Am I missing something in adding a configuration to enable it?

FYI: We have implemented our own message body reader which extends from javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader for mapping JSON to object.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: have you added validation annotations on the java class to be validated?

Comment: @MasterMind I think you ar e talking about annotations like "@Size" , "@NotEmpty" etc..Yes, I did add the annotations to the java class and tried to test it with data which should fail the constraint but it didnt!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a `javax.validation.Validator` object in your MessageBodyReader and use it to validate classes annotated with `@Valid` in your `readFrom()` method. This is how Dropwizard's Jackson Provider does it.

So the code looks something like this:

```
private static final Class<?>[] DEFAULT_GROUP_ARRAY = new Class<?>[]{ Default.class };
private final XmlMapper mapper;
private final Validator validator;

public MyMessageBodyReader(XmlMapper mapper, Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
    this.mapper = mapper;
    setMapper(mapper);
}

@Override
public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type,
                       Type genericType,
                       Annotation[] annotations,
                       MediaType mediaType,
                       MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                       InputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
    return validate(annotations, super.readFrom(type,
            genericType,
            annotations,
            mediaType,
            httpHeaders,
            entityStream));
}

private Object validate(Annotation[] annotations, Object value) {
    final Class<?>[] classes = findValidationGroups(annotations);

    if (classes != null) {
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(value, classes);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException("The request entity had the following errors:",
                    ConstraintViolations.copyOf(violations));
        }
    }

    return value;
}

private Class<?>[] findValidationGroups(Annotation[] annotations) {
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation.annotationType() == Valid.class) {
            return DEFAULT_GROUP_ARRAY;
        } else if (annotation.annotationType() == Validated.class) {
            return  ((Validated) annotation).value();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have an example [here](https://github.com/yunspace/dropwizard-xml/blob/master/dropwizard-xml/src/main/java/com/yunspace/dropwizard/xml/jersey/jackson/JacksonXMLMessageBodyProvider.java#L60), where I've written a custom XML Jackson Reader + Writer with Validation support.

Comment: I dont want my validation code to reside in the reader as then it becomes reader's responsibility. I am looking for validator implementation that gets invoked before reader or after reader's serialisation to validate the incoming json and return thereof, if invalid.

Comment: Hibernate validator validates a deserialised POJO, therefore you can't invoke it on a incoming JSON string. The annotations you want to use such as `@NotEmpty` or `@Size`, are declared in your POJO. So how can you do validation when the POJO isn't deserialised first?

If you really want to verify JSON string without deserialisation, you would need to use a JSON schema (similar to XSD for XML) to verify against. And it won't be annotation based.